# Normal distribution and choosing final number

Tags: normal-distribution

I've read a paper which used normal distribution in order to assign a number to each entity as follows:

> Each user has a quality measurement qi ∈ [0, 1]. For the experiments
>   in this paper, the quality of a user is chosen from a normal
>   distribution with 0.5 for mean and 0.5 for SD

May you please help me, what exactly they are saying?

Comment: Do you know what a normal distribution is?  Here, they appear to be saying that the $i^{th}$ user is assigned a value $q_i$ which is chosen at random, with probability specified by the normal.  To be sure, there is about a $32\%$ probability, using the numbers you gave, that the value $q_i$ will be greater than $1$ or less than $0$...but I suppose that such values are simply discarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user gets a "quality" value between 0 and 1. The probability of getting a number is symmetric about $0.5$, and is given by a *normal distribution*, which defines the probability of being a given "distance" away from the mean.

That "distance" is measured in *standard deviations* and called the *$z$-value*. The formula for the $z$-value of a given measurement $x$ is $$z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$$

where $\mu$ is the mean, $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

The *standard normal distribution* has $\mu=0,\sigma=1$. The above formula effectively converts values on another normal distribution to the equivalent value on the standard normal distribution. The equivalence for the statement you refer to, is explained in the diagram below. Values outside the valid zone for $q_i$ are likely ignored.

[image: the standard normal distribution and its equivalence]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is here that the paper doesn't explain how to assign Xi in order to find out qi. I guess that the paper is fully using a randomly approach in finding qi using normal distribution. Am I true?

Comment: @SiavashR yes, that's exactly what they're doing. There are ways to express the distribution at any mean and standard deviation, it's just easier to run it it by equivalence. So they'll find a value on the standard normal at random, which I hope doesn't need explaining, then convert it to a $q_i$.

Answer (score 0):

The normal distribution is a "bell shaped curve", that appears often when the variable you are measuring is a result of multiple effect which act more-or-less independently of each other.

In a normal distribution more people will be clustered around the average, with a few above and below average. Also about 50% will be above average and 50% below average (the normal distribution is symmetric, not skewed). The normal distribution is described by two values: the mean and the variance (or the square of the standard deviation)

Distributions that approximate normal include: the heights of men chosen at random. the marks achieved in a test paper and, The amount of error made in a scientific measurement. You can generate normally distributed values in Excel with the formula `=norminv(rand(),0.5,0.5)`

There is an inconsistency in the example, as if qi is distributed normally, then its values could be bigger than 1 or less than 0. Perhaps another part of the paper describes how this fits with the claim that each qi is between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is here that the paper doesn't explain the value of qi. I guess that it is using a fully random approach for qi. It is true?